# Variable is set equal to zero after eighth iteration

Tags: c, file-io

I'm doing an assignment on c-style files for class. I've gotten pretty far, but in my loops, a variable behaves weirdly. After the eighth iteration z is set to 0 when it should be set to 9. I'm not sure why it would be set to 0 if it's clearly adding 1.

```
//Aaron Hervey
//Date: 09/23/2020

#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

struct Room{
    long size;
    char * details;
    char * name[sizeof(size)];
    char * desc[sizeof(size)];
    char * exit[sizeof(size)];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    //Variables
    unsigned int i = 0;
    char * holder;
    long size;
    char choice;
    bool fa = true;
    FILE *fl;
    Room p;
    //Error checking commmand line
    if (argc < 1) {
          printf("Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
          return -1;
    }
    char test[] = "room1";
    fl = fopen(test, "rb");
    if (fl==nullptr){
        printf ("Error opening file");
    }
    
    //Get File Size
    fseek(fl, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fl);
    p.size = size;
    rewind(fl);

    //Allocate whole fize size to var & Write file into struct member
    p.details = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
    fread(p.details, 1, size, fl);

    //Write file into struct
    unsigned int z = 0;
    while (true){
        if (z==8){
            int test = 1;
        }
        if(z>0){
            holder = strtok(nullptr , "~");
            if(holder == nullptr){
                break;
            }
            p.name[z] = holder;

            holder = strtok(nullptr , "~");
            p.desc[z] = holder;

            holder = strtok(nullptr , "~");
            p.exit[z] = holder;
            z++;  
        }
        else{
            holder = strtok(p.details , "~");
            if(holder == nullptr){
                break;
            }
            p.name[z] = holder;

            holder = strtok(nullptr , "~");
            p.desc[z] = holder;

            holder = strtok(nullptr , "~");
            p.exit[z] = holder;
            z++;
        }
    }

fclose(fl);

    //Menu
while(fa){
    printf("> ");
    scanf("%c", &choice);
        switch (choice){
            case 'q':
                fa = false;
                break;
            case 'l':
                printf("%s\n", p.name[i]);
                printf("%s\n", p.desc[i]);
                printf("Exits: %s\n", p.exit[i]);
                i++;
                break;
            case 'w':
                break;
            case 'n':
                break;
            case 's':
                break;
            case 'e':
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I have a loop that continuously stores file info into the arrays from a struct but I can't seem to understand why the iterating variable isn't cooperating

Comment: `scanf(" %c", &choice);` -- note the added space..

Comment: Wait, I don't see that in my code. Are you telling me to add it? @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: In `// Menu` each time the user enters a choice and presses **Enter** a `'\n'` is left in `stdin` which you take as your next input. Adding a space before the `"%c"` ensures that is ignored.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I was having problems with input but couldn't pinpoint what @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Better, `char choice[256];` and then `fgets (choice, sizeof choice, stdin);` then `switch (*cihoice) { ... }` which is equivalent to `switch (choice[0]) { ... }`. That way, even if the user enters `"e is for everyone..."` the complete line is consumed and you compare against `'e'` just the same, but the chance of any one input effecting the next is eliminated...

Comment: `Room p;` -> you are using a C++ compiler to compile C.

Answer (score 2):

```
long size;
char * name[sizeof(size)];
```

This declares `name` as an array of usually 8 (might be 4, or other values) `char *`.

```
p.name[z] = holder;
```

When `z` equals 8, you are writing out of bounds of the array, so anything could happen, one of these things being overwriting the variable `z` itself.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on what I could do to rectify this? I want them to be flexible or large enough to handle any file